# Could there be legal reprecussions for using a TV show/Anime/Series as a design for T-Shirts?

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property

For example, if I wanted to make a T-shirt of a character for the Arrow Tv series, but I drew it myself/designed it myself. Is it legal for me to sell products (T-shirts) of it?

Comment: You may want to add your country of jurisdiction, though I suppose the answer is "yes" (on the title question) and "no" (on the body question) in most cases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You can make a [derivative work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) if:

- the original is not under copyright,
- you are the copyright owner,
- you hold a licence from the copyright owner that says you can, or
- your usage is [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) or [fair dealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_dealing) as applicable.

For your proposal, the image is copyright, you don’t own it, you don’t have a licence and what you propose is neither fair use nor fair dealing. You can’t do it and you can be sued if you do.

Comment: :+1, agreement and correct conclusion, but I would amend the last point to "probably neither fair use nor fair dealing". Depending on how far from "normal"/recognizable depictions of the subject matter the artist goes, it may actually fall into fair use or fair dealing: "Luke Skywalker with a lightsaber" is infringing but "farm boy with a laser sword" is not necessarily so. More relevantly, using the name of the show or photo of the actor in costume is right out, but "bowman in a hood" might be allowable, regardless of inspiration.

Comment: @Dale M It may be worth noting that if the show itself already sells such merchandise, it may also be a trademark violation.